# Loading a partialview with a model that has an ID. BeginForm returns the edited model, but the ID is lost?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model:

```
public class Wellbore
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Planned Depth")]
    public double PlannedDepth { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Reference Depth")]
    public double ReferenceDepth { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Reference Point")]
    public string ReferencePoint { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Use Section List")]
    public bool UseSectionList { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Well Fluid Specific Gravity")]
    public double WellFluidSpecificGravity { get; set; }
    public List<WellboreSection> WellboreSections { get; set; }
    public int WellId { get; set; }
}
```

And i have a controller

```
    public ActionResult Index(int wellId)
    {
        var wellbore = _service.FindBy(x => x.Id == wellId).SingleOrDefault();
        return PartialView("~/Views/WellManagement/Wellbore.cshtml", wellbore);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public void Wellbore_Edit([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Wellbore wellbore)
    {
        if (wellbore != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            wellbore = _service.Edit(wellbore);
        }
    }
```

And the view....

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Wellbore_Edit", "Wellbore", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal"}))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Id, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
       <div class="col-md-3">
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ReferenceDepth, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReferenceDepth, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

And so on....

When i load the view with the Index method in the controller, everything works fine. The object contains all of the appropriate values.

When i have done my editing in the view, i click save, and the form posts back. I recieve an object in the Wellbore argument, and if i look at it, all of the properties has values, except Id and WellId....

WellId is not used in the form, so this i might understand, but Id is defenitly used. How come this is is not in the object on it's way back?
How does these objects get created? Whats the internal function of this....

Comment: Disabled inputs don't post back

Comment: Is that a feature? to me it sounds very strange... In my case i want to display it, but the user should not be able to edit it, and of course i would need it when updating the entity in the database.... how does one solve that problem then?

Comment: You can make it readonly instead of disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because disabled = "disabled"
Please use @readonly="readonly" in place of disabled like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new {@readonly="readonly"})
```

Comment: If i use readonly, will it then be disabled? I want the "look" to be disabled.....

Comment: @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen  Yes, it would work perfectly fine